# Firing D3 event for an element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have attached a `click` event to an element of a D3 chart:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const vis = {}
vis.svg = d3.select(element)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
vis.g = vis.svg
    .append("g")
const circles = [20];
const myCircles = vis.g.selectAll('circle').data(circles).enter()
myCircles
    .append('circle')
    .attr('id', (d, i) => { return 'myCircle' + i})
    .attr('cx', 100)
    .attr('cy', 100)
    .attr('r', (d, i) => d)
    .attr('fill', 'gainsboro')
    .attr('stroke', 'grey')
    .on('click', function(event, d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke', 'black')
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke-width', '2px')
    })
```

Is there a way to fire this `click` event from outside of an element? I tried doing this:

```
d3.select("#myCircle0").click();
```

But it does not work.
Is there an alternative way of firing D3 event for a specific element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dispatch the event:

```
d3.select("#myCircle0").dispatch("click");
```

Here is a demo with a slightly modified code, dispatching the click to the first circle:

```js
const vis = {}
vis.svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500)
vis.g = vis.svg
  .append("g")
const circles = [20, 20, 20];
const myCircles = vis.g.selectAll('circle').data(circles).enter()
myCircles
  .append('circle')
  .attr('id', (d, i) => {
    return 'myCircle' + i
  })
  .attr('cx', (_, i) => 100 + 50 * i)
  .attr('cy', 100)
  .attr('r', (d, i) => d)
  .attr('fill', 'gainsboro')
  .attr('stroke', 'grey')
  .on('click', function(event, d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('stroke', 'black')
    d3.select(this).attr('stroke-width', '2px')
  });

d3.select("#myCircle0").dispatch("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```